# How can i separate jsp in differents folders with Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my AppInitializer:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.app")
    public class AppInitializer extends
            AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements
            WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
            ctx.setServletContext(container);

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                    "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            servlet.addMapping("/");
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }
    }
```

And this is my AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acfcm.app")
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolverForClasses() {
        ResourceBundleViewResolver viewResolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setBasename("views");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setOrder(2);
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/");
    }
}
```

What I want is how to change the AppConfig to put .jsp in differents foldes into the project because right now only can save it in /WEB-INF/views/ and there is a lot of .jsp!! I want to have two more folders to see my project like:

- WEB-INF/views/moduleOne/
- WEB-INF/views/moduleTwo/
- ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is all fine; it will look for your JSPs starting in /WEB-INF/views/

Most people do like you say and break up JSP views under folders like /admin,  /common, etc.

The way you do this is to specify the subfolder in the controller. For example, in your controller, you could return:

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response)
    {
    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("someValues", new ArrayList());
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("admin/index","model", myModel);
    return mv;
  }
```

Doing it like the above, you can put your JSP under 
/WEB-INF/views/admin/index.jsp

Of course, your mappings (/admin) doesn't have to match the directory structure (/WEB-INF/views/admin) but we chose to make both match, to make it faster to find the code (if controller mapping matches the dir structure).

The important thing to remember is that whatever you put in that ModelAndView first param, Spring will prepend and append the values you defined in your code:

```
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
```

So, if you return ModelAndview("/pierre/was/here/something"), Spring will try to find the JSP at location: "/WEB-INF/views/pierre/was/here/something.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to have the configuration as yours, and in the request handler controller methods, use the view names as `moduleOne/view1`, `moduleTwo/view2` etc.